# Why do both Batty and Kowalski talk about 'living in fear' and 'time to die' when fighting Deckard?

Tags: plot-explanation, blade-runner

Why do both Batty and Kowalski talk about 'living in fear' and 'time to die' when fighting Deckard in *Blade Runner*? Is it just a coincidence? Its just to tell that replicants are angry at living in fear and dying soon? I don't know how much of a coincidence it is, or in how many different ways this could have been said.

Kowalski

Batty

Answer (score 8):

Replicants in the Blade Runner world are generally slaves. Especially the four who are *on the run* trying to just live.

With that said, Batty, the ring leader, likes to talk heady. Kowalski is represented a little dumb, literally supposed to be the muscle of the group. He is likely only repeating the things he heard: things Batty said to him to convince him to run, to find Tyrell, to find a cure.

Deckard is literally hunting down run away slaves with a dated kill switch, with the plan to kill them. Given the situation, and that Blade Runner is a Noir detective film its unsurprising the characters all talk about death and running in fear, its the theme of the movie.

Heady and repeated speeches are the norm.

Comment: I'm not familiar with your use of "heady." What do you mean by it?

Comment: As in ‘intellectual’, ‘philosophical’ or perhaps academic.

Comment: @morbo that's not what "heady" means. It means impetuous, precipitate; wilful, headstrong, unruly; capricious; intoxicating, potent; very exciting or exhilarating

Comment: You forget language has colloquial parts. I have and used heady in such a way for years and know entire locals who also do.

Comment: Do not edit my posts @OrangeDog

Comment: @morbo fine, but the majority of people who view this post will not understand you

Comment: Your preference for "heady" in all honours, but in general, please refrain from telling people not to edit your posts. That's not how we do things on SE.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson, I'll ensure such an issue doesn't happen again.

Comment: -1 for use of "heady" in a way I've never heard it before, one that appears to be directly opposed to the actual definition.

Answer (score 1):

The replicants, for all their strength and intelligence, are children.

They know they are getting close to death (4 year life span), and their fear is a driver for them (they are living in fear).

Batty is a combat model, a killer. In the instant when Deckard is hanging by his fingertips, Batty (who is dying, which we can see by his need to drive the nail through his hand to feel anything), realises there is a greater value in saving Deckard and allowing him to live, so reaches a more enlightened state where he is no longer "living in fear", and is prepared for his demise.

He faces death without fear ("time to die") becoming more human than many of the human characters in the movie.

Comment: My thoughts on this issue is that Batty was teaching Deckard some empathy (which sounds ironic) . He waits until the last second to save him. Believe thats because he just wanted Deckard to feel how it is to live as a replicant/slave, and not kill him, even though he is a replicant hunter. But I don't think this is an answer to my question.